# A differentiable manifold which isn't a subset of $\mathbb{R}^n$, definition 2.1. do Carmo Riemannian Geometry

Tags: differential-geometry, manifolds

I'm reading through Riemannian Geometry from DoCarmo. Chapter 0 section 2 defines what a differentiable manifold is:

> A *differentiable manifold* of dimension $n$ is a set $M$ and a family of injective mappings $x_\alpha : U_\alpha \subset \mathbb{R}^n \to M$ of open sets $U_\alpha$ of $\mathbb{R}^n$ such that:

> 1. $\bigcup_\alpha x_\alpha (U_\alpha) = M$

> 2. for any pair $\alpha,\beta$ with $x_\alpha (U_\alpha) \cap x_\beta (U_\beta) = W \neq \emptyset$, the sets $x^{-1}_\alpha (W)$ and $x^{-1}_\beta (W)$ are open sets in $\mathbb{R}^n$ and the mappings $x_\beta^{-1} \circ x_\alpha$ are differentiable

> 3. The family $\left\{ (x_\alpha,U_\alpha) \right\}$ is maximal relative to the conditions (1) and (2).

What is an example of differentiable where $M$ isn't a subset of $\mathbb{R}^n$?

Comment: I feel like this definition allows $M$ to be $a)$ not second countable and $b)$ not Hausdorff. Certainly this is bad?

Answer (score 1):

Any smooth $m$-dimensional manifold $M^m$ can be smoothly embedded into $\mathbb{R}^{2m}$. So, the question would really be what $M^m$ can't be embedded into $\mathbb{R}^d$ where $d < 2m$. An example of this would be real projective space of dimension $m$. For more on this, you could look into the Whitney embedding theorem. The Nash embedding theorem may also be of interest.

Comment: For the projective space, it is when $m$ is a power of $2$ that it does not embed in $\Bbb R^{2m-1}$